# JSCover with PhantomJS - TypeError: 'null' is not an object

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs, jscoverage

When I try to run JSCover with PhantomJS, I see below ERROR:

**Steps followed:**

1) Run the JSCover Server:

`java -jar ~/JSCover/target/dist/JSCover-all.jar -ws  --report-dir=report`

2) Run the PhantomJS runner with JSCover:
`*phantomjs --debug=true ~/JSCover/src/test/javascript/lib/PhantomJS/run-jscover-jasmine.js`
`localhost8080/<app>/module/framework/test/SpecRunner.html`

`TypeError: 'null' is not an object`(evaluating''document.body.querySelector('.description').innerText')`

`phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():3`
  `phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():22`
  `phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():22`
`2013-09-19T16:36:07 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript result QVariant(, )` 
2013-09-19T16:36:07 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript "(function() { return (function () {
                jscoverage_report('phantom');
            })(); })()" 
2013-09-19T16:36:07 [DEBUG] WebPage - evaluateJavaScript result QVariant(, ) 
2013-09-19T16:36:07 [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: 5 ( "Operation canceled" ) URL: `localhost8080/<app_home>/lib/backbone/1.0.0/backbone.js?cb=0.5381254460662603`

Comment: Do you use Jasmine's HtmlReporter or some other one? I believe you see that error because the page doesn't contain the markup created by the HtmlReporter.

Comment: Same problem with the htmlreporter and the current jasmine. The tests are fine from karma with karma-jasmine, but jasmine reporter does not wait for window onload before running the tests. I have a document.body.appendChild in one of the describe blocks. I am testing DOM.

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue that I ran into yesterday. It turns out that the example script does not work for newer versions, so I built a new Phantom Script that works for Jasmine 2.X which fixes it. You can locate the working script here in my repository:

https://github.com/tkaplan/PhantomJS-Jasmine

Comment: Very nice script, though I spotted a bug :    
        for(var j = 0; j < specs.length; j++)
                    {
                      console.log("   it: " + specs[i].innerText);
                    }

You should have probably done specs[j].innerText

Comment: Thanks, if you want to continue off of it and make pr I'll accept it. But I'm not working on it since I use other test runners now like karma.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue when I try running Jasmine with PhantomJS.
I realized that the latest version of Jasmine-html.js (jasmine-2.0.0-rc2)
does not go along with PhantomJS's run-jasmine.js (phantomjs-1.9.2-windows).

In the jasmine-2.0.0-rc2 version of Jasmine-html.js,
The '.description' class is not available if all tests passed.
This 'description' class is created only if any test failed.

Thus, when I run the phantomjs with all tests passed, I get the above error message.
I modified run-jasmine.js to adapt to Jasmine-html.js (jasmine-2.0.0-rc2) to 
resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading your tests asynchronously?  I use requirejs for modular javascript.  It is also used to load the test specs:

```
<script data-main='SpecRunner' src='/test/scripts/libs/require.js'></script>
```

When using JSCover, the `run-jscover-jasmine.js` script does not account for this async behaviour, so the DOM nodes referenced in the query do not exist (yet).  I modified the script to delay the waitFor call by 1 second:

```
page.open(system.args[1], function(status){
    if (status !== "success") {
        console.log("Unable to access network");
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        // Added 1s delay here
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            waitFor(function(){
                return page.evaluate(function(){
                    return document.body.querySelector('.symbolSummary .pending') === null
                });
            }, function(){
                var exitCode = page.evaluate(function(){
                    console.log('');
                    console.log(document.body.querySelector('.description').innerText);
                    var list = document.body.querySelectorAll('.results > #details > .specDetail.failed');
                    if (list && list.length > 0) {
                        console.log('');
                        console.log(list.length + ' test(s) FAILED:');
                        for (i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
                            var el = list[i],
                                desc = el.querySelector('.description'),
                                msg = el.querySelector('.resultMessage.fail');
                            console.log('');
                            console.log(desc.innerText);
                            console.log(msg.innerText);
                            console.log('');
                        }
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        console.log(document.body.querySelector('.alert > .passingAlert.bar').innerText);
                        return 0;
                    }
                });
                page.evaluate(function(){
                    jscoverage_report('phantom');
                });
                phantom.exit(exitCode);
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Depending on the amount of code loaded, you may have to increase the delay.

Comment: I am using same kind of setup with run-jasmine.js where running tests outside of team city works fine. When running inside team city i got the following from build log. E:\APPS\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\7e813246cff2b28\jQuery\src\Jobs.Web.UnitTests\S‌​pecRunner.html [15:10:50][Step 4/4] in directory: E:\APPS\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\7e813246cff2b28 [15:11:05][Step 4/4] 'waitFor()' finished in 12006ms. [15:11:05][Step 4/4] Process exited with code 0 I tried increasing wait time but no help